# SFMC: Query Based Data Extension Help

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

We have a synchronized data extension from Sales Cloud coming into our SFMC instance. In the Opportunities table, it is possible for a single customer to have multiple Opportunities in various stages, depending on which dealership received the lead. We have Opportunity stages such as New, In-Process, Dormant, Deposit Received, etc.

What I'm trying to do is write a query that will only bring in emails from Opportunities in a "Dormant" stage but that also does not have an opportunity based on the same email in either "In-Process" or "Deposit Received"

Any guidance on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Can you please share, what you have tried so far to achieve your goal - e.g. the SQL query you have built, but which isn’t working as expected.

Comment: I guess that's the problem...I'm not even sure where to start. My initial thought was to pull all the data into a Python app, clean it there, and then export that into a data extension with the API but if there is a "cleaner" solution than that, I'd much rather go that route.

Comment: You need to build a destination Data Extension with the fields you want to populate. Then create a SQL Query activity in Automation Studio, joining your opportunity DE with contacts or leads, selecting the data from the Synchronised Data Extensions

Answer (score 0):

You would have to roll up your sleeves a bit and write the SQL yourself. But here is something to get you started.

- Create a query activity in Automation Studio
- Write a JOIN query for Opportunity to OpportunityContactRole and JOIN on OpportunityId
- Then JOIN OpportunityContactRole to Contact on ContactId
- Use a WHERE clause where the Stage is “Dormant”
- Also AND NOT EXISTS using a nested SELECT statement WHERE Stage is “In-Process” OR “Deposit Received”

[image: Salesforce Objects Relationships]

Answer (score 0):

Okay this will depend a bit on your data model, but if you're trying to get emails from **Contacts** then they are most likely linked to Accounts, and similarly Opportunities are linked to accounts.

In that case you could write a query like this:

```
SELECT *    // all fields
// renaming your synchronized DE to something easier to read, i.e. "Accounts"
FROM Salesforce_Accounts__c Accounts    
  // relate Opportunities to Accounts  
  INNER JOIN Salesforce_Opportunities__c Opportunities    
    // explain how they are linked
    Accounts.Id on Opportunities.AccountId   
  INNER JOIN Salesforce_Contacts__c Contacts
    Accounts.Id on Contacts.AccountId
// now let's filter
WHERE
  Opportunities.Stage = "Dormant"
```

All of this you'll need to put into a "Query Activity" (see the docs) and you'll need to put the result in another DE that you need to create.

However, there's a much easier way to go about it if you don't want to get into SQL, although you will need to get a 3rd party app called [DESelect](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-18). Then you could do the same with drag-and-drop which would look a bit like this:

[image]